# Are Cantor's set theory and the axiom of choice well accepted nowadays?

Tags: set-theory

Is there a "more consistent" theory ? Do mathematicians agree about the validity of the results obbteined by this theory ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Your question is *still* very unclear.

Comment: got better now ? I don't know how to make it more clear, like i'm wondering if people accept results derived from the notion of ordinals, cardinals, transfinite induction, etc...

Comment: As opposed to what? Hardly any mathematicians work in anything but ZF, and very few even bother thinking about whether they need the C.

Comment: Yes, they are ... About "more consistent" theories, it makes little sense. *Consistency* is ON/OFF : a theory is either *consistent* or *inconsistent*. The "usual practice" in math is to assume that a theory is *consistent* until an inconsistency has been found.

Comment: You should give more context to your question, and perhaps clarify what "Cantor's set theory" means, because I haven't really heard that term being thrown around in this context.

Comment: It means assuming the existence of sets like $\omega +1$. And I thought that the non-existence of a supremum to the set of all cardinals/ordinals would be a contradction, or that people acctually worked on solving this kind of problem but it looks like this idea is well accepted nowadays

Comment: The ideas which Cantor gave have been widely accepted in comparison to his day, yet I have seen mathematicians (a few) reject the notion of infinite sets.

Comment: I don't understand how $\omega+1$ means there is a supremum to the "set of all cardinals/ordinals"? Since when is the "set" of cardinals/ordinals just $\omega+1$?

Comment: I don't understand where I said one thing implies the other

Comment: [Not in those exact words, but it kinda felt like this is what you are saying](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347855/are-cantors-set-theory-and-the-axiom-of-choice-well-accepted-nowadays#comment2740334_1347855).

Comment: you may wanna start lower buddy  The "." separates phrases what comes before it not necessarily has to do with what follows it

Comment: In a word,yes. Modern set theory was built by many mathematicians. The logical consistency of Choice with the axiom system ZF (Zermelo & Frankel)  was shown by Godel circa 1937. BTW another comment here , concerning about  omega+1 : .... omega is the set of FINITE ordinals.(Set theorists often use omega and the set of natural numbers interchangeably).  Omega,  and its members , are the members of omega+1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the question is unclear. You want to know if most mathematicians still work with set theory, roughly as formulated by Cantor, and you want to know if most mathematicians worry about issues raised by using the axiom of choice.

For any reasonable definition of "most," the answer is that most mathematicians still work with set theory, roughly as formulated by Cantor, trusting that some or other formal codification of this is consistent, and that most mathematicians do not worry about the axiom of choice.

Comment: Pray tell, what is set theory as formulated by Cantor?

Comment: @Asaf It means "naive set theory". Set theory nowadys is "Axiomatic Set Theory".

Comment: @Nicolas Bourbaki: In that case, we don't work with set theory "as formulated by Cantor", because naive set theory is blatantly inconsistent.

Comment: This is also my experience. A lot of mathematical areas can get away with naive set theory and it seems pointless to be too precise about axioms. This doesn't mean that most mathematicians are unaware of deep results in axiomatic set theory. It just means that, in their research, they do not generally encounter good reasons to bother.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, I never seen a single mathematician even mention the Axiom of Choice during lecture/talk. If they choose elements in every open cover, then they are perfectly okay with that, and never even make a big deal about it. But after two months of choosing elements in open covers, they decide to give a proof of Tychonoff theorem, and announce "today we will use Axiom of Choice in the form of Zorn's Lemma". It is as if they never even realized that they been using Choice for the past two months.

So the short answer is, most mathematicians use choice all the time without even realizing it (unless they are logicians). They only mention it when they form it in the form of Zorn's Lemma or Well-Ordering Principle.

The classic joke describes this situation perfectly: "The Axiom of Choice is obviously true, the Well Ordering Principle is obviously false, and Zorn's Lemma is a nice technical result to use in a proof".

Comment: that's kind of sad in a lot of ways but ty

Comment: @onlyme Why is it sad? That is only describing the attitude of mathematicians, not if there are any problems with the mathematics itself.

Comment: Outside of set theory courses (where the axiom of choice is an actual part of the curriculum, so it's often mentioned explicitly), I did meet (and hear about) more than a handful of teachers that wanted to know when they employ the axiom of choice, and whenever a set theory grad student was in the crowd, they would defer this question to him. More often than not, this happens in commutative algebra courses. But I ran into this in an analysis courses as well.

Comment: lol the attitude is kind of sad because people don't seem to understand the axiom, they don't realize when they're using it and it seems that a few think about the consequences of it. But your answer was great, was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @AsafKaragila In commutative algebra courses they only mention it once when they use the fact that every ring has a maximal prime. Then the next several months the lecturer uses it blatantly without even mentioning it ever again. In analysis courses it comes up when one "constructs" a non-measurable set. So after 2 months of using axiom of choice arguments in the development of measure theory they decide they need to mention it only when they talk about non-measurable sets. It is pretty funny to me.

Comment: Strange, I could have sworn that I saw the proof that the definitions of Noetherian rings are equivalent; or that I saw the Hahn-Banach theorem being stated and proved; or... you know, other things that use the axiom of choice. But maybe I was just learning those on my own, and had a dream that I saw them in class. Oh, or the Baire Category Theorem? Open map theorem? Closed graph theorem? Not every linear functional is continuous on $\ell_2$? Uhh... what else? You're underestimating the use of the axiom of choice in modern mathematics.

Comment: (Also the classical "joke" is due to Jerry Bona, and it ends with "who knows what's going on with Zorn's lemma".)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think Baire-Category uses dependent choices not full choice, but we are getting off topic. I am not sure what you mean by, "You're underestimating the use of the axiom of choice in modern mathematics.". I am not underestimating anything. I said above that choice is used everywhere and most mathematicians never even to bother to mention it. Unless they use it in the form of Zorn's lemma.

Comment: If it's not provable in $\sf ZF$, it's using the axiom of choice. You can start to investigate and dwindle the assumptions, but then non-measurable sets don't require the axiom of choice either. In fact all measure theory being taught is not using the axiom of choice at all by that logic! Because it's consistent that the axiom of choice fails, and $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, and then you don't use the axiom of choice at all in these constructions. How great is that? I'll run to tell my measure theory professor now.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am not exactly sure what the point of this last comment is. It is not exactly relevant to what was said earlier.